# SQLAlchemy ORM - adding two class attributes to a single table

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I have independent class-A which is inherited in an another class-B. Class-A doesn't have a table of its own, it shares the columns in the Class-B's table. If I have to map these classes using a mapper, how will I write a mapper. 
Example:-

```
class Class_A(object):

    def __init__(self,name, value):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value

class Class_B(Class_A):

    def __init__(self, id, amt):
        self.id = id
        self.amt = amt

Table_B = Table('tableB', metadata,

    Column('id', Integer)
    Column('name', String(20))
    Column('value', String(20))
    Column('amt', Integer)
)
```

Please help me.

Comment: you can say mapper(Class_B, Table_B).    Class_A by itself would remain unmapped.  If you wanted to map Class_A by itself you'd have to clarify what exactly would be in the table for a Class_A by itself.

Comment: In case if Class_A and Class_B inherit from Object (independent) and have the attributes in the same table, how will the mapping done. Currently I have a scenario where object1 is inside another object2. Please explain this scenario also.

Answer (score 1):

The SA documentation for the ORM discusses a number of different use cases for handling object inheritance across a relational table structure. It looks like your use case is the [Single Table Inheritance](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/inheritance.html#single-table-inheritance) model. There are good examples listed that resemble your example closely and should be easy to put to work.